# Interstitial ads is opening other activity

Tags: java, android, admob

i have a problem.

First activity > A.class
Second activity > B.class

I want to show interstitial ads at only A class. But if i enter A.class and go to B.class quickly, ads opening B.class. But B. class have this

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
    System.exit(0);

}
```

For the reason, if ads open at B.class, app is closing.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: remove System.exit(0)

Comment: i don't want to remove system.exit, it is necessary. i wat to disable showing ads on other activity.

Comment: In activity A, before calling mInterstitialAd.show(), check the state of activity, if its already paused then don't show it.

Comment: @Prashant thanks :)